independence of parametrizations of curves
Let $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{C}$ a $C^1$ curve. I need to show that length of $\Gamma$ is independent of parametrization.
I managed to show that if $z_1:[a,b] \to \mathbb{C}$ and $z_2:[c,d] \to \mathbb{C}$ are two parametrizations of $\Gamma$, which are equivalent (i.e. there exists a diffeomorphism $t:[c,d]\to[a,b]$, $t'(s) > 0$ such that $z_2(s) = z_1(t(s))$) then $l(\Gamma) = \int_a^b|z_1'(s)|ds = \int_c^d|z_2'(s)|ds$. But if the parametrizations are not equivalent it is possible to show this?

You can show that any such parametrization must give a length that agrees with the 1-dimensional Hausdorff measure of the curve, viewed as a subset of $\mathbb C$.
You should be able to find the details in Falconer’s book Fractal Geometry.
